# Topic Model LDA: Problem with removing of special character

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling, stop-words

I want to remove the special character `—` from my simple corpus. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case. I tried different variations of `gsub`. Also, I tried to copy the dash `—` from my R object. I use XML data and changes it in a simple corpus. For this I used `tm_map`.

If I use

```
text <- c("Today is the weather nice — I want to go to the beach —")
text_new <- gsub("—", "", text)
```

The output is

```
Today is the weather nice — I want to go to the beach —
```

whereas I'd like my output to be

```
Today is the weather nice I want to got to the beach
```

If I define the text as a vector than it works. But as a corpus R doesn't recognise the symbol `—`. How can I detect the long dash?

Answer (score 0):

It could well be that you are searching for a `-` with your `gsub()` function, while the text from the PDF contains a long dash or any other type of dash that only looks similar. Have you tried opening the R object with the text and copy pasting the `-` you want to delete from there to your `gsub()` function?

Comment: Thank you for your words of welcome. I hope my edited question is better. I tried to implement your advice, but R doesn't recognize the dash as a long dash.